# Create a duplicate site using "Get-PnPSiteTemplate" will not copy the custom site permissions and the list indexes

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell

I have a SharePoint site named "source" and I want to create a duplicate site for it named "duplicate", so I ran the below commands:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/source" -interactive

Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out "PnP-Provisioning-File.xml"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/duplicate" -interactive

Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Path "PnP-Provisioning-File.xml"
```

But I have noted that these 2 things will not be copied:

- Custom SharePoint groups which have custom permission levels, where I will get these errors on the SharePoint groups during the invoke process:

> ```
> WARNING: Cannot find principal 'Source-PPM Contributors', cannot grant permissions
> WARNING: Cannot find principal 'Source-PPM Contributors without Delete', cannot grant permissions
> WARNING: Cannot find principal 'Source-PPM Contributors without Delete & Create', cannot grant permissions
> ```

- List indexes

So is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same with saving the site with the content as a template and recreating it. It contains everything, and inherits permissions from the parent site. I don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: saving site as template is not available in modern sites which have script disabled